# jQuery Ajax call not working in IE, JSON respond not getting through

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call with a json respond to work in IE, but nothing is happening. It is currently working fine in other browsers.

I have read a lot of places, that there are some general issues with ajax and IE, but none of the solutions have helped.

I have also tried using the  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); but that doesn't fix it, it does not seem to have anything to do with caching.

Any help i highly appreciated.

The code is pasted under.

JS:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".loginForm", function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var url=$(this).attr("action");
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (data, status)
    {
        if(data.success == "success"){
            window.location.replace("dashboard.php");
        } else {
            $('#loginResponse').html(data.success).css("color", "red").fadeIn().delay(2000).slideToggle();
        }
    }
});
```

});

PHP:

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);

    if(isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = 'SELECT user_id, first_name, password FROM arbor_admin_users WHERE username=?';

    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->bind_result($uid, $fn, $pwhash);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        while($stmt->fetch()){


    //        if ($password === $pw) {
            if (password_verify($password, $pwhash)) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = $uid;
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $fn;
//            header("Location: ../dashboard.php");
            echo json_encode(array('success'=>"success"));
            exit();

            } else {

        echo json_encode(array('success'=>"Wrong username or password!"));

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>"Wrong username or password!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `nothing is happening` No error in console? Is request send or what? Only on IE? Which IE version? What about browser's cache? Check at least than the submit event is fired

Comment: Console gives me nothing, and yes.. only IE, and so far, it seems to be all IE versions, in other browsers, it works flawlessly.. and it is not the cache no :(

Comment: I meant the browser's cache, meaning you have to hard clear browser cache (ctrl+F5 if i'm correct). I'm not talking about cached request. And still can you check than submit event is fired?!

Comment: I have disabled cache in the browser, so cache is not the problem :) in network, i can see that it calls the php file, so submit is fired.

Comment: So bind error handler of ajax request or just check what returns server. You said: `nothing is happening`, but for sure something is happening, but what?

Comment: http://imgur.com/iJMbciG does this give you anything?
I havent done much debugging.. pretty new at ajax.
how can i bind an error handler?

Comment: It means than your request is successful, so now test in success ajax callback what's going wrong. Set some console.log to see from where your code is failing or use `debugger;` statement: `success: function (data, status)
    { debugger; /*...*/});`

Comment: I just noticed that is says initiator/type = xmlhttprequest.. does that mean it tries to read it as XML? when it is actually json.

i just tried to put in 
    `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }`
and the response is the correct response.. so it seems that IE doesn't interpret it correctly.

Comment: If you remove `datatype: "json",` and check in success `console.log(data);`, what do you get?

Comment: I get nothing, the success function doesn't seem to be run at all.

ye, i just checked in other browsers.. the success function is never ran in IE.. any idea why?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm out of idea.

Comment: No problem.. i have found the problem.. and it looks like that IE is not interpreting it as JSON, even though i tell it to.. and because of that, the success function is never ran. but how to fix it.. well thats a headscratcher.

Comment: But so by removing `datatype: "json",` it should have reach the success callback. That's said, that's IE so i'm not really surprised something else strange happen... Anyway, glad you have at least spotted the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time debugging, i found out that

```
    data: new FormData(this),
```

doesn't include the submit button in IE, but does in all other browsers.

So to fix it, i just removed:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {
```

and problem solved :)